# Sizing Text for SmartPhones that Have Text Zoom Enabled

Tags: android, css, mobile, blackberry, media-queries

I don't know if this applies to Android or iPhone. I have an Android 2.3.3 for testing and an iPod Touch 3rd generation with iOS 5 on the way. But I know its a problem on my buddy's new Blackberry.

Basically, my buddy has text zoom (or whatever you call it) turned on so that text is displayed at like 150% of its normal size on any web pages he views on his Blackberry. Well, I have optimized my sites with media queries so the text already increases to 150% on small screens. On his device, the device setting is compounded with my CSS settings and the text becomes absolutely enormous!

I'm sure this is a problem for a lot of users since there are so many sites out there with tiny text that has to be zoomed for mobile.

So my question is:  Is there some kind of best practice approach or any solution to dealing with these folks that have turned on text-zoom or an equivalent feature?  How can I make my text not be obscenely large and unuseable for them? Do I just leave it in their hands to turn the text zoom down?

Also, does Android 2.3 have some kind of feature like this that I should be testing for?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a solution to cases where users have increased their text size.  If someone knows of one, please indicate so.  In the meantime, I DID find out that you can make device-specific adjustments for mobile devices with these:

-moz-text-size-adjust
-webkit-text-size-adjust
-ms-text-size-adjust

Details can be found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-size-adjust

I'm going to mark the question as answered since I don't believe a solution to the original issue actually exists at this time.